# Orbot Tor on android nougat issues

Tags: configuration, orbot, android

I installed Orbot for android on a Nexus 6p device, it works fine on first launch, but when I tried to "exit", it kept launching in the background, going to the app again, the UI was toggling fast between active and inactive (yellow and black).
Is Orbot not yet supported on Nougat devices, or is it a configuration issue ?

Comment: Orbot hasn't been updated for Android N yet. Granted, normally older apps work fine on newer Android versions, so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: That's what i thought, but given it's current state, it's quite unusable

Comment: I know it's not recommended, but for the time being, maybe you could try one of the other Tor apps?

Comment: To keep this information current, I have an Android N (LineageOS 14.1) device and Orbot currently works.

Comment: I have similar issues on LineageOS14.1 (Nougat)